# Exception thrown inside an anonymous inner class not caught

Tags: java, android

I have a method that has an anonymous inner class. I want to throw an unchecked exception from inside the anonymous inner class, and catch it outside of the class. I'm having trouble doing this.

```
@Override
public void showAchievements(){

    androidLauncher.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                loadingView.showLoadingView();
                Games.getAchievementsClient(androidLauncher, signedInAccount)
                    .getAchievementsIntent()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Test exception");
                        }
                    });
            }  catch (Exception e){
                // Not catching
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My exception is not being caught. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing an exception in a callback method.

Either the callback method is never invoked, it is not invoked synchronously, or 
the code that ultimately invokes the callback method is catching it.

Without seeing more of your code, it is impossible to say which.

Comment: There isn't much more code for me to show as most of it is the Google Play Services SDK. One thing I did notice though was that the `addOnSuccessListener` method adds the `OnSuccessListener` on the Main Thread, while my method is running this on the UI thread. I suppose that this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to move your try-catch-statement inside the `onSuccess` method. The listener is called at a later point.

Comment: hmmm, that's not really what I want though. It looks like the issue is that the listener is ran on the main thread instead of the UI thread where I'm doing the try catch.

Comment: Yes, they run on different threads because it is called after it has been initialy refistered. That is exactly why you have to put the try-catch-handler inside that method, if you want to or not. Things just don't work the way you want them to work. Get used to it.